# Loop through constant in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a constant declared in the components.ts file as below

```
dish = DISH;

const DISH = {
  id: '0',
  name: 'pizza',
  image: '/assets/images/ppizza.png',
  category: 'mains',
  featured: true,
  label: 'Hot',
  price: '4.99',
  comments: [
       {
           rating: 5,
           comment: 'Test1!',
           author: 'John',
           date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Test2!',
           author: 'Paul',
           date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
      {
           rating: 2,
           comment: 'birthday',
           author: 'Cent',
           date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       }
   ]
};
```

I am trying to show the data in components.html , inside the comments using loop, but I am not getting the information. I tried below:

```
<div fxFlex="40">
    <p><strong>Comments</strong></p>
    <mat-list fxFlex>
      <mat-list-item *ngIf ="dish">
        <p matLine>
          <span> {{dish.comments.comment}}  </span>
        </p> 
        <p matLine>
          <span> {{dish.comments.rating}}  </span>
        </p>
      </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
  </div>
```

How to show all the comments and rating? what is the mistake made ?

Comment: You need to loop the comments since it is array of objects

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data) directive:

```
<mat-list fxFlex>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish?.comments">
    <p matLine>
      <span> {{comment.comment}}  </span>
    </p> 
    <p matLine>
      <span> {{comment.rating}}  </span>
    </p>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a list of comments inside the **dish** object, so you loop through the list inside of it (`dish.comments`):

```
<mat-list fxFlex>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let commentObj of dish?.comments">
        <p matLine>
          <span> {{commentObj.comment}}  </span>
        </p> 
        <p matLine>
          <span> {{commentObj.rating}}  </span>
        </p>
      </mat-list-item>
 </mat-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the comments array in the DISH json and loop through it.

```
<mat-list fxFlex>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish?.comments">
   <p matLine>
    <span> {{comment.comment}}  </span>
   </p> 
   <p matLine>
    <span> {{comment.rating}}  </span>
   </p>
  </mat-list-item>
```